# Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime returning wrong external storage path

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

No matter what path I set in sd card in WP emulator, external storage path always returns `D://` as Path.

[image]

[image]

```
var sdCard = (await KnownFolders.RemovableDevices.GetFoldersAsync().AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false)).FirstOrDefault();
           string path = "";

           if(sdCard != null)
           {
               path = sdCard.Path;
               await sdCard.CreateFolderAsync("Backup", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
           }
```

Though it shows wrong path, its creating the `Backup` folder in the right location. i.e

```
E -> Temp -> SdCardWP -> Backup
```

Here also some weird thing is happening, if I try to recreate the `Backup` folder after deleting it, its not creating again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only SD Card emulator - it won't return the path that's on your desktop.

Remember that on the phone you will also have letter `D:` (probably the first free letter for removable device).

Comment: Its confusing, would you please explain how its creating Backup folder in that location?

Comment: @Subha Treat WP emulator as a virtual machine - it has its own drives and resources. Now you insert the SD card (with your path E://SDCard//), the selected folder is mounted in the WP System as drive D. You can't access your desktop from the WP emulator. Some information about WP emulator you can find [at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn629629.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I am getting it now. To access WP's Isolated Storage I have used [ISETool.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh286408%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), for removable drive what tool I have to use? Also its not creating the folder all the time, why its so?

Comment: I think the files should be synced when you eject the SD card - as the text besides the tick says `sync back to local folder when SD card is ejected`. As for tools you may also take a look at [IsolatedStorageSpy](https://isostorespy.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I downloaded IsolatedStorageSpy and the tool is really cool. But its showing only local(IsolatedStorage) folder and not external storage folder. Is anything is wrong in my code?

Comment: @Subha As the name says it's IsolatedStorage - it works similar to ISExplorer. Have you tried to eject the sd card?

Comment: Sorry, as it was given as answer for removable storage tool I thought it would work for external storage also. Thanks for your support, you cleared many of my doubts :)